# error: method get not allowed for url scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm using scrapy and the following code for crawling a website. Website request method is POST.

```
    def send_request(self):
        payload = self.payload
        request_body = json.dumps(payload)

        yield scrapy.Request('https://api.divar.ir/v8/search/1/real-estate',
                             method='POST',
                             body=request_body,
                             headers=self.headers,
                             dont_filter=True,
                             callback=self.parse(),
                             )
```

I got this Error:

> b'Error: Method GET not allowed for URL /v4/1/real-estate'

How can I handle it?

[image: Website]

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you're running?  Are you sure that API expects JSON?  That's not standard for POST.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is the URL of website: https://divar.ir/s/tehran/real-estate ... How can I send request to it's API?

Comment: I don't have a clue.  If they have an API, you'll need to have documentation.  And, of course, I don't read Farsi.  I didn't see any "search" URL on that page.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you, but no need to search ... just go to the Network tab in inspect and scroll down the page

Comment: That's asking quite a lot of me.  I still don't see any /v8/search/1/real-estate URLs.  I see /v8/prediction-components/1.

Comment: @TimRoberts I've added image of that